# Facing error in npm install on aws ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, npm

I'm trying to deploy my angular 2 application on aws ubuntu.
I have successfully install npm on ubuntu. but by the time I'm trying to build my application on using "npm install", I'm facing "extract:typescript → gunz" error and process getting killed as shown in the attachment. Can someone please help me.?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps need to provide more memory for the ubuntu swap

Comment: There is enough memory available:-
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            236M     0  236M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  1.8M   47M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  1.4G  6.3G  19% /
tmpfs           244M     0  244M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           244M     0  244M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000

Answer (score 0):

You need to add swap on your Ubuntu

This will fix this error and npm will install all angular data successfully 
follow this instructions
 [From here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)